# Download file from GCP VM using Chrome "completes" before downloading 100%

Tags: google-chrome, google-cloud-platform, download, jupyter-lab, google-cloud-vertex-ai

- I have a `.tar.gz` file in a GCP VM (accessed through JupyterLab via VertexAI) that is ~600 MB.
- I tried to download it through Google Chrome but the download completes itself at around ~12X MB which is well before 100% at ~600 MB.
- I tried to decompress the archive but it is corrupted as expected.
- Moreover, interestingly, every time the download stopped at a different size.

  - trial 1: 127 MB
  - trial 2: 128 MB
  - trial 3: 120 MB

Any idea what happened?

20240205 EDIT: I changed to Microsoft Edge but the problem persists. Now I got larger file sizes by downloading from Edge.

- Trial 1: 574 MB
- Trial 2: 554 MB
- Trial 3: 503 MB

Comment: Open the Chrome debugger (Inspect) and look for errors. Verify that the response headers have the correct content type and content length. Your question does not have enough details about the object or the transfer process.

Comment: I now changed to Microsoft Edge but the problem persists. But the "downloadable" file sizes were larger.

Comment: I did not recommend changing browsers. Reread my comment.

Comment: But does this situation mean irrelevant to chrome?

Comment: Chrome is not the issue.

Comment: Are you downloading via the JupyterLab UI? Have you tried SSH download or GCS transfer?

Comment: John, because I am new to chrome debugger so I tried to change the browser first.
Hi gogasca, I have just tried SSH download and it worked fine (i.e. 100% download completed successfully).

Comment: For these few days the SSH does not start downloading at all. I think I have to re-open this issue.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @gogasca and as commented by @Johnny Tam, you can try `SSH` to download the file completely i.e., 100% that would help to resolve the issue.

Posting the answer as community wiki for the benefit of the community that might encounter this use case in the future. Feel free to edit this answer for additional information.

Comment: This does not solve the problem asked. The problem is with browser downloads.

Comment: For these few days the SSH does not start downloading at all. I think I have to re-open this issue.