# Download files from VM through SSH won't start

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ssh, download

- I have a 3.4GB `.tar.gz` file in a VM, which I tried to download through SSH but it won't start at all and became failed after some time.
- Then I tried to create a small .txt file, which is 4KB and the download was successful

In such case, I suppose downloading large files from VM are more difficult than small files.

Do you have any advice on downloading large files from VMs?

As much as possible I want to avoid splitting files into smaller parts.
Especially because I have much larger files up to ~300GB and I wonder why 3.4GB became a hurdle because previously such a file size should not be a problem to download from GCP VM through SSH.

Moreover, recently I have created a similar question that deals with JupyterLab download. I don't know if these situations are  related. [Download file from GCP VM using Chrome "completes" before downloading 100%](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77935350/download-file-from-gcp-vm-using-chrome-completes-before-downloading-100?noredirect=1#comment137402409_77935350)

Comment: What command are you using to download those?

Comment: I used the GUI download function on the top right hand corner of the SSH window -> paste complete path of file -> start download.