# Download file from GCP VM using Chrome "completes" before downloading 100% (reposted)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, download

It is a reposted thread from [Download file from GCP VM using Chrome "completes" before downloading 100%](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77935350/download-file-from-gcp-vm-using-chrome-completes-before-downloading-100?noredirect=1#comment137402409_77935350) as it sinked down and couldn't find a solution.

- I have a `.tar.gz` file in a GCP VM (accessed through JupyterLab via VertexAI) that is ~600 MB.
- I tried to download it through Google Chrome but the download completes itself at around ~12X MB which is well before 100% at ~600 MB.
- I tried to decompress the archive but it is corrupted as expected.
- Moreover, interestingly, every time the download stopped at a different size.

  - trial 1: 127 MB
  - trial 2: 128 MB
  - trial 3: 120 MB
- I changed to Microsoft Edge but the problem persists. Now I got larger file sizes by downloading from Edge.

  - Trial 1: 574 MB
  - Trial 2: 554 MB
  - Trial 3: 503 MB
- Changing to download through SSH didn't help.

Comment: Hi @Johnny, It appears that this issue has to be investigated further, so if you have a support plan please create a new GCP [support case](https://cloud.google.com/support/). Otherwise, you can open a new issue on the [issue tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) describing your issue.